# What is the difference between Ansible template module and copy module?

Tags: ansible

What is the difference between Ansible template module and Ansible copy module?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While very similar, template serves an extra function.

- [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) takes a file from host,
   *"as-is",*
   and copies it to the remote destination.
- [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) takes a file (template) from host,
   *changes variables based on Jinja2 filtering,*
   and copies it to the remote destination.

You could use template to copy a file without template formatting from host to the remote destination.

An example of copy over template is when you need to import a custom config file based on parameters from the host (or elsewhere), such as a web config file that takes host/credential properties from a database instance.  Note the same could be achieved by using copy/[lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html)--this is just a different way of doing so.

Comment: I wonder, though, if one should only invoke template when it's functionality is needed. Why add the (admittedly miniscule per-occurrence) overhead of calling jinja2 what have yous on static content, which could possibly impact your runtime if you had too many of them, or if you were operating in a resource-constrained environment.

Justing musing out loud, really. Someone pitch in with their two cents :)

Answer (score 0):

**Ansible copy module**

1.) It copies a file from the local host to a remote server

2.) The copy module is perfect for those files that are always consistent across all of your system.

for eg: copying /etc/passwd from host to remote machines

3.) A application which you wants to copy from host to remote server.

**Ansible template module**

1.) The template module also copies a file to a remote server, but it allows you to use Jinja2 to modify a template to a file dynamically.

2.) Variables can be used in files such as Ansible Facts

jinja2 templating is little bit confusing

Answer (score -1):

Its almost similar, the only difference is "**COPY**" module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html#copy-module) will write the exactly same data on the controller node where are "**TEMPLATE**" module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) will first check for if any variable is present in the playbook, if present, it will first convert the variable to its value then writes the data on the controller node, we "**TEMPLATE**" supports **jinja2** codes.

Comment: When answering to an old question like this one, mind to read the other answer. In this case, I don't really see how your answer is different than the one [posted four years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37677622/2123530).